# What is the correct way to parse IPs and CIDRs out of text in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I found many threads about this topic, with distinct and complex answers.

For IPv4:

```
ip = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', file)
```

That works for `8.8.8.8` but not for `8.8.8.8/32`. I tried to add some `(?:/(\d+)` to catch the `/X`. Without success.

Now I also see IPv6 IPs in my file. Do you really have to regex-search for IPv6 IPs the same way? Is there some easier way to search for IPs in text with Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern (for IPv4):

```
[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}(?:\/[\d]+)?
```

Which matches the optional subnet when present. Here's a [***demo***](https://regex101.com/r/XGSEFI/2).

For matching in python, you'll need to do this:

```
ip = re.findall(r'\b[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}(?:\/[\d]+)?\b', file, flags=re.M)
```

Assuming, `file` is a multiline string. If not, you'll need to do `file.read()`.